# How to get branch name from commit id using azure Devops REST API?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

Scenario: I need to get when was the latest commit done in the repo and by whom, and to which branch did that user do the commit on?

Solution:
I'm using python azure.devops module. and here is my code:

```
cm_search_criteria = models.GitQueryCommitsCriteria(history_mode='firstParent', top=10)
commits = git_client.get_commits(repo.id, search_criteria=cm_search_criteria, project=project.name)
for i in commits:
    datetimeobj = datetime.strptime(i.committer.date.strftime("%x"), '%m/%d/%y')
    last_commit_on = datetimeobj.date()
    last_commit_by = i.committer.email
    break
```

Now how do I get the branch name to which the user had committed the code? In the UI we can see the branch name... how can i get the same data using Azure Devops REST API ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03o4K.png)

Answer (score 0):

you may need to use [Stats - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/stats/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to retrieve statistics about all branches within a repository, then evaluate the latest commit, you also need to consider argument of `baseVersionDescriptor.versionOptions` of **firstParent**

I'm not sure if Python wrapper module support this seems like the github project is achieved now.